# What is recommended using Drupal web services or CiviCRM APIs

Tags: drupal, cms-integration

What is recommended to collect data from CiviCRM to external Drupal application and why? [Drupal web services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) or [CiviCRM API](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Using+the+API)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you should call the CiviCRM API directly. This allows you direct access to the CiviCRM system.

If you use Drupal Web Services you still would need to wrap the services around CiviCRM API calls (or direct calls if needed).

So Drupal Web Services just adds additional complexity to something that the CiviCRM API does an excellent job of all ready.  Just use the CiviCRM API services.